# More than one parameters in URL Struts2

Tags: struts2, ognl

I wanted to pass more than one parameter for an action. but when i build the URL using Struts2, it builds with only one parameter. May i know what is went wrong in the below code?

```
<s:url action="loadValidLevelValueDropDown" id="levelvalueURL" escapeAmp="false">
  <s:param name="hierarchyId" value="searchAttribute.hierarchyId.id"></s:param>
  <s:param name="valuebycoulmn" value="refcolumnName%{#level.count}"></s:param>
</s:url>
```

result is,

```
/appname/loadValidLevelValueDropDown.action?hierarchyId=1
```

Comment: What is `refcolumnName` and `#level.count`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `value` attribute of `<s:param>` tag takes OGNL expression as a value. Your `refcolumnName%{#level.count}` value is not a valid expression so parameter is not being appended to url.

If your `refcolumnName` is a collection than you can access it like that:

```
<s:param name="valuebycoulmn" value="refcolumnName[#level.count]" />
```

if it supposed to be a string than you need to append it like string:

```
<s:param name="valuebycoulmn" value="'refcolumnName' + #level.count" />
```

Comment: Yes you are rt. i just tried to append constant with iterator count. valuebycoulmn=refcolumnName1.